# how to enabled allow_url_include and allow_url_fopen in .htacess

Tags: php, mysql

.htacess

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /
allow_url_fopen On 
allow_url_include On
```

Iv tried adding this to my .htaccess but no used i tried this

```
   $contnt = file_get_contents('http://site/files.php');
   echo $contnt;
```

but im getting this error

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function dijkstra() in /home/a2515416/public_html/algorithm.php on line 34
```

when im using xampp everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: Post the full error message - it should include a line number. Then post that section of code.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function dijkstra() in /home/a2515416/public_html/algorithm.php on line 34 <--- this work fine using localhost xampp my host disabled the allow_url_include and allow_url_fopen

Comment: Looks like the file algorithm.php can't find the `dijkstra()` function in an included file. Are you sure all the files on your local system have been uploaded to your ISP?

Comment: yap everything.... bcoz i just upload the folder then change every link. to web host

Comment: The function isn't executing because it's not defined. The message is quite clear. The `dijkstra()` function is not a PHP function, so it's defined in a PHP file somewhere. Check your error logs for any warning about 'could not include' - that should point you at the solution.

Comment: ok i check my error logs

Answer (score -1):

Considering your code is working on your localhost and an undefined function error in your host, your host is using an older version of PHP.

**file_get_contents()** was introduced in php 4.3 only.

Make sure your server is loaded with the latest version of php or php version >=4.3.

Comment: @K Abhishek im using Php 5.2.7 is this something to do with restriction to my host ?

Comment: What is the php version on your server ?

Comment: my xampp php version PHP: 5.4.7 my host Php 5.2.7

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem. The code is failing trying to call a function in algorithm.php

Comment: i think the function cannot be executed becoz of the restriction. exactly how to unblock restriction set by host.

Comment: No - this is about a function that is defined in a PHP script somewhere, but is not being included. `.htaccess` has no relevance unless you're trying to include a file from a remote website. If you are, consider what happens to your site when that file is removed, or hacked. Included files should be local.

Comment: why is it working on my localhost mike and when i change from local to webhost im having getting that error :(